# Can you call a CLR Injection into SQL Server from C++?

Tags: c++

Does anybody know if you can you call a CLR Injection into SQL Server from C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your C++ project with /CLR option and use C++/CLI to invoke your CLR Injection code. Certainly that makes your C++ project dependent on .NET Framework.